# Fazer com que o form envie se apenas determinados campos forem preenchidos

Tags: php, email

Quando submeto o form ele está verificando se todos os campos foram preenchidos. Quero que apenas nome, email e telefone sejam obrigatórios para que o form seja submetido.

Tenho o seguinte código

```
<?php
$subjectPrefix = '[Matricula - Master Clinic]';
$emailTo = 'email@email.com.br';
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $nome    = stripslashes(trim($_POST['nome']));
    $email   = stripslashes(trim($_POST['email']));
    $telefone   = stripslashes(trim($_POST['telefone']));
    $cro   = stripslashes(trim($_POST['cro']));
    $endereco   = stripslashes(trim($_POST['endereco']));
    $cidade = stripslashes(trim($_POST['cidade']));
    $estado = stripslashes(trim($_POST['estado']));
    $mensagem = stripslashes(trim($_POST['mensagem']));
    $pattern  = '/[\r\n]|Content-Type:|Bcc:|Cc:/i';
    if (preg_match($pattern, $nome) || preg_match($pattern, $email) || preg_match($pattern, $subjectPrefix)) {
        die("Header injection detected");
    }
    $emailIsValid = preg_match('/^[^0-9][A-z0-9._%+-]+([.][A-z0-9_]+)*[@][A-z0-9_]+([.][A-z0-9_]+)*[.][A-z]{2,4}$/', $email);
    if($nome && $email && $emailIsValid && $subjectPrefix && $mensagem){
        $subject = "$subjectPrefix";
        $body = "<b>Nome:</b> $nome <br /> 
                <b>Email:</b> $email <br /> 
                <b>Telefone:</b> $telefone <br /> 
                <b>CRO:</b> $cro <br /> 
                <b>Endereço:</b> $endereco <br /> 
                <b>Cidade:</b> $cidade <br /> 
                <b>Estado:</b> $estado <br /> 
                <b>Mensagem:</b> $mensagem";
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.1' . PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= "From: $nome <$email>" . PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= "Return-Path: $emailTo" . PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/". phpversion() . PHP_EOL;
        mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
        $emailSent = true;
    } else {
        $hasError = true;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Você só tem dois `if`'s nesse código, que são os únicos que podem estar validando algo que você não queira, o que exatamente você não quer validar e esta sendo validado? Qual a dificuldade em editar essas condições? Precisa ser mais claro um pouco...

Comment: Editei o post Kenny. É porque o form só esta enviando se todos os campos estiverem preenchidos, se não ele retorna:
<?php if(!empty($hasError)): ?>
<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Houve um erro no envio, tente novamente mais tarde.</div>
<?php endif; ?>

Comment: Tem que rever seus IFs. Criar um método só pra validar o campo expecífico se torna mais compreensível.

Comment: Exporte um `create table` da sua tabela no banco de dados e poste na pergunta, já tenho 99% de certeza do que é o erro...

Comment: Como assim @Kenny Rafael? Não tem banco de dados.

Comment: Nossa, viajei bonito...

Comment: @MarceloVictor, só existe uma possibilidade dessa variável `$hasError` não ser `empty`, se alguma das condições no seu `if` forem falsas, tente dar um `var_dump($nome, $email, $emailIsValid, $subjectPrefix, $mensagem);die;` antes do `if` e verifique qual delas é falsa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que o que você quer é isso:

```
if($nome != "" && $email != "" && $emailIsValid && $telefone != ""){

...
```

Pois apenas se os campos `$nome` , `$email`  e `$telefone` forem vazios o formulário não será submetido. Ou seja, são campos obrigatórios.